# In-app purchase testing mzfinance.InAppBuyLoginRequired_message (sandbox)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am working on an in-app purchase...  I had things working fine in the simulator/(sandbox mode).  I’m still working on some stuff with the app and testing.  Today when I tested the in app purchase I get.

In-app purchase testing mzfinance.InAppBuyLoginRequired_message (sandbox)

I looked in iTunes connect and it said “Rejected” under the in app purchase.  I didn’t put complete descriptions but didn’t think it mattered because I had previously developer rejected the app.

So I deleted the in app purchase... uploaded/rejected another binary and added the new in app purchase.  I used the same apple-id to test.  The first time, it said Successful.  I try it again and I get the same error message.

In-app purchase testing mzfinance.InAppBuyLoginRequired_message (sandbox)

Any idea what’s going on?  I assume the code is fine since I haven’t changed it.  Its something with iTunes connect setup or something.

Comment: did you got the solution? i am also facing this issue

Comment: This seems to be a problem on Apple's side. We are running into the same kind of issue here.

Comment: same here. (only on simulator not device)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, i couldnt buy any in-app because i've seen every time :

mzfinance.InAppBuyLoginRequired_message (sandbox)

Earlier i tested my in-app purchases on this test account and everything was fine.
I created new test account in iTunesConnect and it helps!.

Go to:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/

Select:

"Manage users" >> "Test user"

Next "Add new user" and create new user with any e-mail adress (i used imaginary e-mail adress).
This work for me, i'm using now this second account to testing.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Same stuff happening since 31 May 2012. Noticed this behavior only in the simulator, on the device everything is ok.

I've managed testing on the simulator every time creating new test user at iTunesConnect. It's very time consuming but otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: I still have the same problem ! Do you still have it ?
It seems the problem occurs when you want to buy a product your already bought. That's why creating a new user each time solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't come when you buy the app for the first time. (Creating new user means buying it first time). It comes when you are trying to restore the InApp purchase and haven't properly handled the restore purchases.

See the "Restoring Transactions" section in [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1).